# audio and video file compressor

Tags: audio, video-encoding

Does anyone know a great audio and video  file compressor?

I currenting compressing wmv to 3gp with AVS software.

when i compress the file its out 250kb and that only about 2mins and 30 sec of video.

i would like to compress the sound and video smaller so that i can add more time to my video.

Comment: If you just want an application to do it, rather than find out how to write an application yourself, then (a) look at Avidemux, and (b) this question isn't programming-related and should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

[FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is probably the best choice. It has a wide-range of formats, flexibility and codec support. There's little comparison. There are a variety of desktop apps that are built on it too, if you need a UI.

Comment: I am converting wmv to 3gp for mobile phone.  will that ffmeg compress my file very small. I want to compress 2mb to 250 kb

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for an application [super (c) is very good at all sort of video compressions](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) tho it has a pretty weird UI

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/).  Find out what codec and resolution your mobile device wants.  If you're lucky, H.264 will be supported.  That codec seems to produce excellent compression these days.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy thing I found the other day. I used QuickTime to File->Export->iPhone my 250MB .avi file and it output the file into four new/different files. Three were in .m4v format and varied in size from 62.3MB to 6.8MB. However the fourth file was a .mov file that was only 381 bytes in size. You read that right. It compressed the video from 250MB to 381b or <1KB. If my math serves me right that is over 600K times smaller than the original file.

Just fyi. Hope this helps.