# Video and audio file

Tags: compression

**Duplicate:** [audio and video file compressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675921/audio-and-video-file-compressor)

---

I would like to compress a wmv 2mb or larger file to  3gp 250kb file for mobile devices.

any great compressors for video or audio?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a huge fan of [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/).  Find out what codec and resolution your mobile device wants.  If you're lucky, H.264 will be supported.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some trouble here. WMV is a container, not a codec, so we can't tell specifically the level of compression we're dealing with and what needs to be changed where, but it may be difficult to get such a dramatic reduction in filesize without making huge compromises, like decreasing the resolution of the video by several orders of magnitude. These compromises may be acceptable for mobile viewing, but there's no guarantee you'll be able to get that filesize down, especially if your file is encoded in a modern codec like H.264 or VC-1.

My first piece of advice is to attempt to locate a good wizard-like transcoder, with a nice non-developer interface on it, etc. Video compression is intense work, and the power tools behind it, and the tools that these wizard-like applications use to actually perform their work, are very complex and take lots of practice and tweaking to get right, and are usually restricted to commandlines. If your mobile device's vendor provides these utilities, for instance, you'll be much better off using them.

If you aren't able to locate such a utility, godspeed and spend lots of time with mencoder and ffmpeg's man pages and IRC rooms. It's not difficult per se, it just takes a lot of study and reading to get acceptable output, especially when you're going after the reductions you've mentioned. Good luck.